# how to create auto increment column which starts with user000001 useruser000002 and so on?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have wrote trigger which applies specific data to specific table. in this table there is column "user_number". this should be like this

user000001 
user000002
user000003
and so on

my codes look like this (this is trigger)

```
insert into maindb.users values 
   (null, #1)this is ID auto increment 
   null,  #2)this is user_number, THE FIELD I WANT HELP WITH 
   fullname, 
   new.position, 
   new.strucutre1,
   DATE_FORMAT(new.action_date,"%d/%m/%Y"), 
   sysdate());
```

> Which version of MySQL are you using?
>   Server version: 10.1.39-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
>   **
>
> What database engine are you using?
>   InnoDB
>   **
>
> Why do you want textual values? This seems like a bad idea...
>   software which i am using requires it.
>   **

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: Why do you want textual values? This seems like a bad idea...

Comment: I made some updates.

Comment: Do not do this. Do not attempt to bend auto_increment to this purpose